# NTFS EFS : How to copy encryption certificates from one file onto (an)other file(s)?

Tags: encryption, certificate, encrypting-file-system, certificate-store

**I would like to copy all encryption certificates associated with one marker-file onto a set of other files.**

Sure, there's the `QueryUsersOnEncryptedFile` function that returns a `PENCRYPTION_CERTIFICATE_HASH_LIST`, and there's the `AddUsersToEncryptedFile` function, that takes a `PENCRYPTION_CERTIFICATE_LIST`.

So, as far as I understand, to copy the certificates over, these hashes need to be converted back into a list of certificates.

To make this transition, I've been messing around with `CertFindCertificateInStore`. That worked up to some extend, but not for all certificates, I don't even know which certificates store(s) I should query... I did tried a few : `CA`, `ROOT`, `MY`, `SPC`, `Trust`, `TrustedPeople`, `AuthRoot` (and even `AddressBook`, which seems to contain an out-dated cache of certificates, as some where already expired) but none of them gave me access to all certificates that I have hashes for.

*So, how can I reliably map a certificate hash back to the certificate itself?*
(Some example code would be nice.)

Thanks in advance!

---

As a side-note:

I would also like to remove all other certificates from these same target files. For this purpose, there's a function available, called `RemoveUsersFromEncryptedFile`, which also takes a `PENCRYPTION_CERTIFICATE_HASH_LIST`.

I imagine this list could be gathered by first calling `QueryUsersOnEncryptedFile` on each file, and pass the resulting certificate hash list to `RemoveUsersFromEncryptedFile` (on the same file).

But there's a caveat: I don't want to loose all certificates, or the files won't be accessible to anyone anymore! *Can I safely zero-out my own (and by extension any other allowed) certificate hash from this intermediate hash list?* (Given that there's also a dedicated `FreeEncryptionCertificateHashList` function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself : There's an API called `DuplicateEncryptionInfoFile` which does exactly what I need. I should have searched a bit further...

Thanks for reading though, I hope this question + answer will help someone, someday ;-)